# Swift 3 example of Bundle(for: XXX)

Tags: swift, swift3

I am making a Swift 3 module. So I need to know the bundle associated with a class in that module. In Swift 2 this was:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

How do I appropriately do this in Swift 3?

[image]

Comment: If you use `self.dynamicType` the compiler should offer you a fixit with the correct version.

Answer (score 9):

Solution:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Comment: What's `type(of: self)` ? Where does it come from? Autocomplete doesn't suggest me such code. Also, looking at documentation can't seem to find anything related to type(of: ). But copy pasting the exact same code doesn't yield any errors.

Comment: Try swiftdoc.org and the Swift 3 version

Answer (score -1):

let file = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "filetype")